# Is there an Java function to find the position of an array element in an sorted array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, indexing

My assignment question goes like this:

> Write a program in Java to store 20 different names and telephone numbers of your friends in two different single dimensional arrays. Now arrange all the names in alphabetical order and display all the names along with their respective telephone numbers.

I came up with this code

```
public class Q7
{
    public static void main()
    {
        String name[]={"Dean","Sean","Daniel","Sheldon","Adi","Raj","Steve","Ava","Riley","Jessie"};
        String Temp[]=new String[10];
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)//Creating another unsorted array to find respective telephone numbers later
        { Temp[i]=name[i];}
        long number[]={7747872132L,7975117568L,4008269466L,8028612214L,9448011416L,949153772L,9591817794L,9845666946L,9448638374L,8182248864L};//telephone numbers of people in name[] respectively
        String temp="";
        for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++)//Sorting
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<name.length;j++)
            {
                if(name[j].compareTo(name[i])<0)
                {
                    temp=name[i];
                    name[i]=name[j];
                    name[j]=temp;
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Name\t\tTelephone Number");
        for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++)
            System.out.println(name[i]+"\t\t\t"+number[Temp.IndexOf(name[i])]);//This is where I need help
    }
}
```

The problem I  am facing is I don't know know to print telephone numbers with respective names. Please help me this is my school assignment.

Comment: Your "linear search" is a sort, and you only sort one of your arrays (you would need to swap elements of `number` whenever you swap `name`(s) - or *better*, create a POJO [plain old java object] that contains both `name` and `number` fields and sort that).

Comment: I always get confused between the two im still a beginner in java. I have edited the question Thank you for you notification

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can you please show me how i can swap elements of ```number``` and ```name``` simultaneously. It would be a great help

Comment: You just repeat the same procedure within your if statement within the loops, but then for the telephone number - and of course a different `temp` variable.

Comment: You first sort the names *and the telephone numbers* at the same index in the loops. Then you create a separate loop to print out the sorted names *and numbers* in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can you please show me how i can swap elements of number and name simultaneously. It would be a great help*

Do not do this in **real** code. Change

```
if(name[j].compareTo(name[i])<0)
{
    temp=name[i];
    name[i]=name[j];
    name[j]=temp;
}
```

to

```
if(name[j].compareTo(name[i]) < 0)
{
    temp = name[i];
    name[i] = name[j];
    name[j] = temp;
    long ntemp = number[i];
    number[i] = number[j];
    number[j] = ntemp;
}
```

Your `temp` array could be eliminated (you only need a *local* and *single* `temp` per element being swapped).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply solve the problem by introducing a copy array `copiedNames` of the `name[]` to preserve the original order.

Then, you would use `Arrays.asList(copiedNames).indexOf(name[i])` to find the index of the String `name` element in the `copiedNames`. The telephone number would be taken from that index.

Below is the working code

```
<!-- language: java -->
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String name[] = {"Dean", "Sean", "Daniel", "Sheldon", "Adi", "Raj", "Steve", "Ava", "Riley", "Jessie"};
    final String copiedNames[] = name.clone();
    final long number[] = {7747872132L, 7975117568L, 4008269466L, 8028612214L, 9448011416L, 949153772L, 9591817794L, 9845666946L, 9448638374L, 8182248864L};// telephone
    String temp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) // LinearSearch
    {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < name.length; j++) {
        if (name[j].compareTo(name[i]) < 0) {
          temp = name[i];
          name[i] = name[j];
          name[j] = temp;
        }
      }

    }
    System.out.println("Name\t\tTelephone Number");
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(name[i] + "\t\t\t" + number[Arrays.asList(copiedNames).indexOf(name[i])]);// fix your need
    }
  }
```

Best,

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Q7
{
    public static void main()
    {
        String name[]={"Dean","Sean","Daniel","Sheldon","Adi","Raj","Steve","Ava","Riley","Jessie"};
        String Temp[]=new String[10];
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)//Creating another unsorted array to find respective telephone numbers later
        { Temp[i]=name[i];}
        long number[]={7747872132L,7975117568L,4008269466L,8028612214L,9448011416L,949153772L,9591817794L,9845666946L,9448638374L,8182248864L};//telephone numbers of people in name[] respectively
        String temp="";
        for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++)//Sorting
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<name.length;j++)
            {
                if(name[j].compareTo(name[i])<0)
                {
                temp=name[i];
                name[i]=name[j];
                name[j]=temp;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Name\t\tTelephone Number");
        for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++)
            System.out.println(name[i]+"\t\t\t"+number[indexOfArray(Temp,name[i])]);  //call indexOfArray here to find the position of unsorted array
    }



    public static int indexOfArray(String[] arr, String input){
         for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
         {
             if(arr[i].equals(input))
             {
                  return i ;
             }
          }
          return -1;    // if the text not found the function return -1
      }

}
```

Hope this can help you !!!